# How to call IdentityServer4 SignOut with LoginId

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

I have an existing IdentityServer4 implementation with external providers I am testing.
I am using postman to authenticate using PKCE which returns an access token correctly. From here I can call my test api and return data with no issues.
The problem I am having is that I would now like to sign out of identity server AND the external provider (AD) before running the test again. Unfortunately I can't see how this can be done.

Looking at our implementation of IdentityServer, I can see the account controller has a SignOut method which expects loginId as a string. I can call this method from postman but can't figure out what to pass as loginId so the method correctly signs out of both identity server AND the external provider.
I have tried passing in both the sub and sid values extracted from the access token but both throw the error "Exception reading protected message" when calling the following code:

```
var logout = await _interaction.GetLogoutContextAsync(logoutId);
```

Sign out works fine from our client but the logic of how the sign out method is called is hidden from me so I'm not sure how to do this manually.
Any help or assistance that can be provided would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll have to build this yourself but the good news is that if the external provider exposes an `end_session_endpoint` you can trigger the signout flow yourself by calling `await HttpContext.SignOutAsync("myexternalschemename")`. Calling this will result in a redirect to said endpoint passing the neccessary parameters.

In our implementation we present an button on the view shown after local signout is done to allow the user to do an upstream signout. This then posts back to the server (with CSRF mitigation) and does a signout of the given scheme.